# View.getEntryCount() returns 1500, but can't get any document by key?

Tags: java, lotus-notes, lotus-domino

I'm writing a simple standalone Java class that uses Lotus Domino's NCSO JAR for remote-connecting to a Domino server.

I'm establishing a session, getting access to a database and then to a view:

```
Session session = NotesFactory.createSession("host", "user", "password");
Database db = session.getDatabase(null, "MyDB.nsf");
View view = db.getView("MyView");
```

Now, I'm printing the number of entries in the view:

```
int count = view.getEntryCount();
```

I get a nonzero number (let's say 1500).

However, I can't seem to load any document by key. For example, for any `letter` in the alphabet, I'm getting an empty document collection with this call:

```
System.err.println(view.getAllDocumentsByKey(letter, false));
```

When I try to load a document by key, when I know that the key exists in the view, I get `null`.

```
Document document = view.getDocumentByKey("DocKey"); // Equals null even though
                                                     // I know that 'DocKey' is
                                                     // the key of an existing
                                                     // document within the view.
```

The very same code is said to be working (although I didn't check it) when using local Notes calls (using `Notes.jar`).

What am I missing?

**EDIT**

I just noticed that `session.getNotesVersion()` returns version 8.5.2. The `NCSO.jar` file that I'm currently using doesn't appear to have a few methods that were added with Notes 8. Therefore, there is a possibility that the `NCSO.jar` file I use belongs to an earlier version of Notes than the one I'm trying to communicate with. Could that be the reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the same code is working locally, then that should rule out the possibility that the first column of the view isn't sorted.  Assuming that, then the most likely issue is that the documents are protected by ReaderNames fields and the identity that you are using for authenticating your session does not have access to the documents.

Comment: Good pointer. Tried to get the readers' list by calling `view.getReaders`, got an empty `Vector` back. Now, I'm assuming that, if my authenticated user ID isn't on the readers list, then I'm going to get an empty `Vector` regardless of whether the view has readers?

Comment: I'm not suggesting that you're having problems with access at the view level. If there were a readers list for the view, I'm pretty sure you would have had a null returned from getView, and getEntryCount would have failed. What I'm suggesting is that the documents that are in the view are protected by ReaderNames fields. The indexer knows about those documents, so that's why getEntryCount comes back with a valid number, but you are not allowed to read those documents (or not the ones with keys that you've tried, anyhow), therefore getAllDocumentsByKey comes back with null.

Comment: I'll attempt to figure it out (have to ask an admin to do that), but at the meantime, I came across something - seems like the `NCSO.jar` file I use belongs to an older version of Notes than the one running on the server (I edited my question accordingly).

Comment: It's unlikely that the version of NCSO.jar is a problem here. All it does is invoke remote methods with matching signatures on the server. It's a very thin layer. Also, IBM is really, really good about backward compatibility, so while you won't have the ability to call newer methods, you can be as close to 100% certain as exists in the tech world that the methods that are in the jar will continue to work with upgraded versions of the server. getAllDocumentsByKey has been around forever, and hasn't changed in a way that would break things. That said, there's no harm in upgrading your NCSO.jar.

Comment: You're right. Upgrading it indeed didn't help. I'll get to check the Readers issue shortly and will accept your answer if and when it turns out to be the culprit!

Comment: I should also add that there was in fact a serious bug that was discovered in getAllDocumentsByKey (and related methods) several years ago, but it doesn't apply to your case.  I.e., it didn't involve a null return. It was a change in behavior that threw an unexpected error when it should have returned data. And it was fixed in 8.5.2.  Here's the info, though, in case it comes in handy: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21424178

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54572/discussion-between-isaac-and-richard-schwartz).

Comment: Umm.. no, sorry. It's not just that I prefer to give my help in a public thread, but it's a little late and I have to get something else done before bed.

Comment: But before I leave, here's a blog post that describes the aforementioned bug more completely than the IBM technote.  Again, I don't believe it applies. I'm just adding it for completeness and in case you're interested.  http://www.bleedyellow.com/blogs/erik/entry/8_5_1_fail_your_code_may_just_break19?lang=en_us

Comment: Many thanks! Will gather all relevant info tomorrow.

Comment: Nope, that wasn't it.

Comment: I am accepting this answer as it's the closest to what appears to be the issue. Changing the database's "default" permissions seems to have resolved the issue. Why? beats me, because the user I'm logged in with has all the needed permissions already.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I understand you right, you want to get all documents where the first (lookup) column of the view contains anything that starts with a specific letter?
E.g. you send "A" to veiw.getAllDocumentsByKey() and expect a collection that contains "Apple", "Alpha", "Amoeba" and "Apricot" to be returned?

I would modify the column in the view to only hold the first letter:
@Left(MyField;1)
Then it would be easy to perform the lookup and see if you get the correct result.

Comment: Actually, no, that's not what I meant. What I'm wondering is what could cause me to not be able to retrieve any document from the view, while still being able to get the count of the entries.

Comment: Since you can see the documents when you look at them in the Notes client, can you check the fields (using document properties infobox) to see if there are any readers fields in them?

Comment: Security isconfigured correctly on these documents: "All readers and up", and my authenticated user is a manager on the database.

Comment: That's the form or doc preperty setting you're looking at, but it is not conclusive. You need to look at every field in the doucment properties box, in the scrolling box on the info tab, and see if any of them are tagged SUMMARY READ ACCESS NAMES or SUMMARY READ/WRITE ACCESS NAMES.